# Originating country for first student visa entry to UK

Tags: visas, uk, canadian-citizens

If you have a Tier 4 Student Visa for the UK do you need to enter the UK for the first time from your home country?

My home country is Canada but I'll be travelling in Europe (Denmark) before entering the UK for the first time on my new Student Visa. I'll be flying in from Copenhagen. Will Immigration have any issues with this?

Comment: I am not aware of such a restriction. It would be impossible to police as well; all international arrivals are mixed together.

Comment: I seem to remember they can give you a good grilling at immigration though like "where did you come from, where are you staying..." etc. Just worried about other questions about my travels.

Comment: They can give you a good grilling if they don't like your hair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an entry clearance (or visa), you can enter the UK from anywhere.  They do not care as long as nothing flags up (like a arriving from Syria for example).

People travelling from North America should try to avoid a flight connection or layover in Dublin however.  The reason for this is that you will be stamped in as a visitor with 90 days leave (under ROI rules) and then will NOT be stamped in by the UK because flights from Dublin are not controlled.  It could make you an inadvertent overstayer.

Based upon what you wrote, you will be travelling from Denmark.  These entry pointed are controlled, so you'll be properly stamped in as a student.  If no one is on duty (which is always a possibility), you should remain airside and speak with the police.  Commentary on this question suggests that you can expect a grilling; this is always the case so have your evidence ready in your carry-on luggage.